# Hidden System Permissions on Permission Sets / Profiles

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, system-permissions

I've been going through an exercise of migrating profiles into a more scalable permission set approach and ran into a few user permissions that don't have a UI checkbox or don't appear to have any documentation from Salesforce:

- EmailAdministration (Email Administration)
- EmailTemplateManagement (Manage Email Templates)
- FlowUFLRequired (Require User Flow Feature License)

The FlowUFLRequired is perhaps self-explanatory from the label, but can someone please explain what these user permissions represent and where (if) they can be located on the Salesforce UI?

Answer (score 1):

I learned about 2 of these the hard way... here is what I was able to find out:

None of these permissions are visible from the UI.

**FlowUFLRequired** controls whether or not you need to allow users to have the 'Run Flow' flag enabled on their user record or not. If it is set to false, they users don't need the flag on their user record to be able to run flows.

**EmailTemplateManagment** controls if a user has access to any email templates at all. If this flag is false, users will not be able to see email templates under any circumstances, it is as if templates don't even exist. If it is true, then they can see whatever templates other permissions allow.

The **EmailAdministration** flag I am not sure about as I have not been able to find exactly what it controls (yet)

Answer (score 0):

I can say that EmailAdministration allows users to view the "My Email Settings" feature under "Settings," but I'm not sure if it does anything else.